# SessionManagerServiceLocator and SessionManagerSoapBindingStub

Tags: java

I want to instantiate an atomic web service and I need to import com.bea.www.wsdl.wlcp.wlng.session_manager.service.SessionManagerServiceLocator;
com.bea.www.wsdl.wlcp.wlng.session_manager.service.SessionManagerSoapBindingStub;

However, I am unable to find them. Is there a new import which i am not aware of? Where can I find the imports?

Comment: Do you mean (oracle.toplink.tools.sessionmanagement.SessionManager) or what

Comment: Nope. it is the import as stated